# Visual Studio - Count instances of a class created in a runtime

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

Is there a tool in Visual Studio allowing to check how many instances of a given class was created during debugging (without editing a code)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SOS library on windbg debugging tool. 
There is a good tutuorial in below link. 
You can list objects with '!Dumpheap' command

https://netmatze.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/using-windbg-exe-and-sos-dll-to-debug-a-net-4-0-application/

Edit: blog link was lost, I've updated with a good one

Comment: Not quite what I need, but thanks for your reply. I want to be able to point on for example class Car and see how many instances of it is currently in the memory

Comment: I think "!dumpheap -stat" gives exactly the count of each object type on the heap memory. Then you can find your class's name and see the count. An example is here: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tess/2005/11/25/dumpheap-stat-explained-debugging-net-leaks/

Answer (score 1):

Bit late to the party, but this question ranks high in the Google and I found a way to show instances in VS.

Once you hit a breakpoint in the Diagnostic Tools (Ctrl+Alt+F2) select Memory Usage tab. Click Take Snapshot button and when it's done click View Heap. You will see instantiated objects, count, memory usage etc.